# Copy image path to click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image. Here,I have written jQuery that looks like below :

```
jQuery('.image').click(function(){
    var path = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Now, I want to fire copy event for this path.When I press ctrl+v button then it print above path so what jQuery should I have to write?

I need to fire copy event automatically. So it is possible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tc875kuL/1/ check

Comment: @Zubairsadiq need to fire copy event automatically.

Comment: You can not just “fire a copy event” and hope that will put stuff into the clipboard. / Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tc875kuL/2/ this is what you want @Nisarg

Comment: and check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tc875kuL/2/)

html

```
<img class="image" src="http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/93/WDF_1369581.jpg" />  
<img class="image" src="https://c7.staticflickr.com/3/2538/3742771246_2648fa4e6e_b.jpg" />
```

css

```
.image{
width:200px;
}
```

javascript

```
$('.image').click(function(){
// Create an auxiliary hidden input
 var aux = document.createElement("input");

// Get the text from the element passed into the input
aux.setAttribute("value", $(this).attr('src'));

// Append the aux input to the body
document.body.appendChild(aux);

// Highlight the content
aux.select();

// Execute the copy command
document.execCommand("copy");

// Remove the input from the body
document.body.removeChild(aux);
 alert($(this).attr('src')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var path;
    $(document).on('click','.image',function()
    {
      path = $(this).attr('src');
    });

    $(document).on('keydown',function(evt)
    {
       if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.which == 86)
       {
       $('#field').html(path);
       }
   });
});
</script>

<body>
   <img src="sample/welcome/thing.jpg" alt="no image" class="image"/>

    <p id="field"></p>
 </body>
```